# numactl --membind

Tags: c, linux, openmp, numa

When using numactl in Linux with the --membind option, let's say I do the following:

```
numactl --membind=0,1,2 ./prog
```

Will the memory for ./prog be allocated on all of NUMA nodes 0, 1, and 2? Or will the memory be allocated only on NUMA nodes 1 and 2 if NUMA node 0's memory is not enough? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The manpage for `numactl` says :

```
--membind=nodes, -m nodes 
  Only allocate memory from nodes. Allocation will fail when there is not enough 
  memory available on these nodes.
```

So, if node 0 does not have enough memory, the memory will be allocated on the nodes 1,2. The actual ration of memory allocated per each node probably depends on the **memory placement policy**.

Comment: But if 0 has enough memory, then all the memory will be allocated in 0, right? What do you mean by saying that ration depends on "memory placement policy"? Isn't it that its going to use full free memory (full free memory=ration) available on node 0, if that's not enough then only it will use full free memory on node 1, and if this is not enough then only it will use node 2? Thanks.